# finding the equation of plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

find the equation of the plane  passing through the point(1,-2,1)  and which perpendicular to the planes 3x+y+z-2=0 and x-2y+z+4=0

i was taking   the  equation 3x+y-2 + C(x-2y+z+4) = 0 where  c is constant and after that  i put coordinates point (1,-2,1)   in  given  equation and i find the value of C,  but i don't know  how to write equation of plane.

i was trying this many times , but i could not get any hints.
if   anybody help me  i would  very thankful to him..

Comment: Why would such an equation be the equation of a plane perpendicular to both planes?

Answer (score 1):

The normal vectors to the two planes are

$$\vec {n_1}=(3,1,1) $$ and
$$\vec {n_2}=(1,-2,1) $$

these vectors are director of the plane $P $ we want.

thus, $\vec {n}=\vec {n_1}\land \vec {n_2} $ is the normal vector to $P $.

but
$$\vec {n}=(-3,2,7) $$
hence the cartesian equation of $P $ is 
$$-3 (x-x_0)+2 (y-y_0)+7 (z-z_0)=0$$
with
$$(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,-2,1) $$
Done!

Comment: I've not seen $\land$ used in this way. Maybe it is a geometry notation? I normally use the standard calculus cross product notation.

Comment: @jdods That is vectorial product of two vectors. it is a vector which is perpendicular to both.

Comment: i don"t understand   how u write n=(-3,2,7)@ salahamam fatima

Comment: @legohlegoh compute the vectorial product n_1 by n_2.

Comment: thanks a lot salahamam fatima

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

The 2 planes intersect, the points

P_1 $(0,2,0)$ and P_2 $(1.5, 1, -3.5)$ lie

on the intersection of both planes, I.e satisfy both equations.

(P_1 is found by inspection, P_2 by solving the 2 sim. equations 1) and 2) below)

Plane 1): $3x + y + z - 2 = 0$, and

plane 2) $x -2y + z +4 = 0$.

The intersection of the planes is the straight line:

$\vec r = (0,2,0)  +t \vec d$,

where the direction vector

$\vec d = (1. 5, 1, - 3.5) - (0,2,0) = (1. 5, -1, - 3.5)$.

The direction vector of this line of intersection is the normal of the plane perpendicular to both planes 1) and 2).

Finally the equation of plane 3):

$\vec n \cdot (\vec r - (1, -2, 1 )) = 0$,

where  $\vec n = \vec d = (1. 5,-1,-3.5)$.